# Validations on named scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, named-scope

I'm struggling to find a way to validate params for named scopes.

**An illustrative setup:**

*models/products.rb*

```
scope :country, -> country {where(:country_id => country)}
```

*controllers/product_controller.rb*

```
has_scope :country, :type => :array
```

*table schema:*

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",                limit: 255
  t.integer  "country_id",          limit: 4
end
```

Example A:
localhost:3000/products?country_id=1

Returns a valid product as expected

Example B:
localhost:3000/products?country_id=111111111111111111111

Returns 111111111111111111111 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4

Which makes sense, because I have limited the country_id column to 4. But instead of increasing the column limit I want to validate the malicious country_id before running the named scope 'country'.

I have researched:

- guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html (applies
  only for saving to the database)
- guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (Segment constraints)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit  where you can restrict the passed in parameters to ones that are acceptable to your business domain

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to restrict any params. I want to validate if the passed parameter meets certain boundaries like length.

Answer (score 0):

You could force the scope to only read the first 4 digits of the `country_id` value:

```
scope :country, -> country { where(:country_id => country.to_s[0..3].to_i) }
```

But it looks very ugly ...

In my IRB:

```
1.9.3p392 :003 > 355555454.to_s[0..3].to_i
 => 3555 
1.9.3p392 :004 > 3.to_s[0..3].to_i
 => 3
```

---

Or eventually return no result:

```
scope :country, -> country do
  if country.to_s.length > 4
    where(id: -1)
  else
    where(:country_id => country)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Thought about the same but as you said it doesn't look like best practice.

Comment: I think you can't do it in another way because the limit to 4 digits is a constraint set at the DB, which Rails is not aware of. I think you have to manually set this constraint on the "ruby side" also --- Or maybe you could rescue the specific error raised and treat it in the rescue block

Comment: I know what you mean, but with limiting country.to_s[0..3].to_i I would pass a wrong id to ActiveRecord. In such a case, where id has 10 digits, an expected behaviour of the app would be to avoid the named scope.I think your second idea with error rescuing might be the right way.

Comment: You could raise a custom error if `country.to_s.length > 4`